# Exercise Package and Marginnote: noanswer

Tags: marginnote, exercises

I've got a huge document with lots of exercises/answers managed by the exercise package (i.e. I'm committed!). I want to print just the exercises, and not the answers, so I turned on the `noanswer` package option. However, some of my answers contain `marginnote`s, and these lead to float lost errors. See below for an MWE.

How can I turn off the answers from the exercise package without getting the marginnote error? (Of course I don't want to print the marginnotes in the answers that I'm not printing!)

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage[lastexercise,noanswer]{exercise}
%compiles if noanswer option removed, or marginnote removed.
\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}
Question goes here
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
Answer goes here\marginnote{margin note}
\end{Answer}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\RenewDocumentEnvironment{Answer}{+b}{}{}`?